# Fundamental Integers solutions to $a^2 +b^2 =c^2 $ only exist if one of a and b is odd and c is odd.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

We have the following Lemma if a,b,c is a fundamental solution of a Pythagorean triangle then exactly one of a,b is even and so c is odd.  Fundamental solution means (a,b)=1. i am not fond of the proof given when i seen the question my solution was as follows does it work?

Consider if c is even and a and b are both odd (they cannot both be even cause then (a,b)=2 at the very least.

$a=2k+1 $ and $b=2 \ell +1 $ and $c=2c'$ so we have.

$4k^2 +4k +1 +4 \ell^2 + 4 \ell +1 = 4(c')^2$

$2k^2 +2k  +2 \ell^2 + 2 \ell +1 = 2(c')^2$ or $(even)+1 = 2 (c')^2$

But $(even)+1$ is odd and $2|[(even)+1] $ a contradiction so if $a^2 +b^2 =c^2 $ has solutions it can only be when only one of a and b is odd.

Similarly $(even)^2$ is even $(odd)^2$ is odd even + odd is odd so $c^2$ must be odd hence c is odd.  if there are solutions.

I really don't like our proof using congruence's this seems more reasonable but im not sure of my set theory logic have i gotten this correct?

Comment: You don't like proof using congruences, you say? You like what you have done better? Then allow me to inform me that this _is_ a proof using congruences. You have just avoided writing "mod" everywhere. You might as well get used to it, because it genuinely makes everything easier to follow and work with.

Comment: i like congruence's sometimes but this was proved 2500 years ago and well Gauss wasn't alive then, doesn't it feels nice to prove something in the way it was found on occasion?

Comment: @Faust: that is the same thing I tell every time I take my horse to go to work.

Comment: @Faust Only if it can be done elegantly. Also, just because they didn't have congruence notation 2500 years ago doesn't mean they didn't have the theory. Finally, your proof can only be a couple of centuries old, seeing how you use $=$ and $^2$ and all (= was first used in 1557). If you want to do it the way the Greeks did it, do it all with words and sentences, referring to the areas of actual squares, rather than squared algebraic variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, but your reasoning can be explained in a more concise form.

Assume that $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple and $c$ is even. Then $a$ and $b$ must be both odd. This implies that both $a^2$ and $b^2$ are $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so $a^2+b^2=c^2\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, contradiction. Thus, $c$ is odd and the $(a,b)$ couple is made by an even number and an odd number.